# Contract function returning a transaction object instead of a BOOL

Tags: javascript, solidity

Why am I not receiving a BOOL object as it is supposed to ? Is the result included inside this weird object i'm receiving ?

Instead of returning the bool result, it returns a weird object like so :

> {"tx":"0x753a987d79c90cb9c71fc312d14472d3d179cb6760708062485c906eb15cc7b1","receipt":{"transactionHash":"0x753a987d79c90cb9c71fc312d14472d3d179cb6760708062485c906eb15cc7b1","transactionIndex":0,"blockHash":"0x892b62649ea689cdd3e47bd4ac49b6a35fcf414ef10d6a1ccdeb473cb1821233","blockNumber":413,"gasUsed":40486,"cumulativeGasUsed":40486,"contractAddress":null,"logs":[{"logIndex":0,"transactionIndex":0,"transactionHash":"0x753a987d79c90cb9c71fc312d14472d3d179cb6760708062485c906eb15cc7b1","blockHash":"0x892b62649ea689cdd3e47bd4ac49b6a35fcf414ef10d6a1ccdeb473cb1821233","blockNumber":413,"address":"0x391737864a8dcdc7b790877dd1b06cfb99067272","data":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001","topics":["0x14d54973c509ce10520c1e0be443c7340095855c124ddda2a3627d4fa542d851","0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001"],"type":"mined"}],"status":1},"logs":[{"logIndex":0,"transactionIndex":0,"transactionHash":"0x753a987d79c90cb9c71fc312d14472d3d179cb6760708062485c906eb15cc7b1","blockHash":"0x892b62649ea689cdd3e47bd4ac49b6a35fcf414ef10d6a1ccdeb473cb1821233","blockNumber":413,"address":"0x391737864a8dcdc7b790877dd1b06cfb99067272","type":"mined","event":"Upgrade","args":{"_tokenId":"1","_upgradeType":"1"}}]}

Comment: Go to this site: https://jsonlint.com/, copy the result you get to there, click the Validate JSON button, and see if your result is contained there. If yes, use basic OO syntax to extract what you are looking for.

Comment: I just read somewhere that Solidity won't return a BOOL if the function modifies state, as it is not mined yet.  Can someone confirm it is the reason why I'm having this result ?

Comment: Another question PLS, if anyone can answer : if a function on contract 1 calls a function on contract 2, and the function on contract 2 reverts because of a failed require() test, will the function on contract 1 revert too, or will it continue its steps ?

Comment: Have you tried what I suggested? Also, have you heard of the acronym "Exception Handling"? All languages provide tools to intercept exceptions and activate user-defined mechanisms (e.g. for graceful run down).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transactions can't return a value to a client that initiates the transaction. When a client initiates a transaction, the callback you provide will be fired twice. Once will be when the transaction is submitted but before being mined (the transaction hash). The second will be after the transaction is mined (the receipt). See [this](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id11) for an example when using web3js 1.0 (it's similar for web3js 0.20.x and for web3j).

However, you CAN return from a non-constant function when called from another contract. Both of those functions will be executed within the same EVM when mined, so returning a value is permitted there.

If you need to return a value from a transaction to a client, you need to either 1) store the value into your contract state and then call a `constant` function after the transaction is mined to retrieve the value in your client, or 2) log via an [event](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.23/contracts.html#events) and setup a listener on your client.

Comment: Thanks! So will calling a function from a contract work 100% of times ? like a bool ?